# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sin (\sin n))^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sin (\sin n))^n$$

which apparently converges (according to the solutions at the end of the book).

I haven't yet learned derivatives or integrals (or L'Hopital rule); I've only learned criteria to determine if a series with only positive terms is convergent or divergent.

I have two problems with this exercises:

- It does not look to me that the series has only positive terms (e.g. $n=5$ yields a negative term) so none of my tests for convergence could be applied
- I'm unable to compute the limit of the sequence as $n \to \infty$, which is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for the series to converge

With regards to the limit, I can definitely do $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sin (\sin n)$ which is indeterminate, it is unclear to me why adding a power of $n$ makes the limit go to 0 and I have been unable to prove it.

So two questions: hints to prove the limit, and confirm my theory that this is not a series of positive terms.

I spent a considerable amount of time on this series (and the respective limit) and I feel that I have exausted the limits of my knowledge at this point.

Comment: Note that $-1\leq\sin n\leq1$. What can you say about the size of $\sin \sin n$ then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this is not a series with positive terms and  $\sin (\sin n)$ is not going to zero as $n\to \infty$.
But since $\sin(x)\in [-1,1]$, it follows that for all integers $n$,
$$|\sin(\sin(n))|\leq \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\sin(\sin(x))|
\leq \max_{y\in [-1,1]}|\sin(y)|=\sin(1)$$
where $0<\sin(1)<\sin(\pi/2)=1$.
Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |(\sin (\sin n))^n|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sin(1))^n<\infty$$
where the last series is a [geometric one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) which is convergent.
This implies that your series is [absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) and therefore it is convergent.

Comment: You might guess that in a sense about a quarter of the terms in a partial sum might be negative (it seems empirically that $24$ of the first $100$ are negative). But they get small fast enough that you can say the overall sum is about $1.4246$

Comment: Nice solution +1. May be it will be good if you find time and elaborate more first inequality.